# Running multiple camera cables from outside to indoors, do I use bushing and wall plate?

Tags: drywall, security, stucco, coaxial-cable

I'm installing a security camera system.  The DVR will be inside, connected to 8 cameras outside.  All cables will terminate at the DVR. I have a picture of the cables below.  I'm going through a stucco outside to drywall on the inside.  I'm really not sure how to manage this many cables like this.  I've done coaxial TV cable, which uses a coaxial bushing on the stucco side and anchors to a wallplate on the drywall side.  But with 8 cables like this, do I use a single bushing on the outside stucco wall?  I can add a standard wallbox like the one in the picture, but what kind of a face plate would I use since I'm feeding the cables all the way through?
Thanks, if somebody knows the right way to do this.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are those cables CL2x/CMx rated for in-wall usage to begin with?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have no clue.  They came with the camera kit, and the kit shows them as indoor/outdoor cameras.  Here's a link.  https://nightowlsp.com/t51p-88-r.html

Comment: Can you read off the cable markings to us please?

Comment: I see no markings on the cable.   Besides the cables are only going from outside to inside.   They are low voltage, 12 VDC.  Do they really need to be plenum rated?

Comment: they don't need to be *plenum* rated, per se, but they do need a UL/NEC rating of *some* sort in order to be just dumped out loosely inside a wall (vs. terminating into a JB)

Comment: this falls under the unrated communication wires, residential, 1-2 family, which I am guessing is to allow cable company to pass their unrated cable wire through the wall.

Comment: @Programmer66 -- yeah, but that requires the cable to terminate in an enclosure or at a primary protector as per 800.48

Comment: Note that my ans actually pass the wire through a conduit through the wall

Comment: @Programmer66 -- that conduit must terminate at a junction box, then, not just dump the cables out into the wall, unless the cables are CL2x/CMx rated for in-wall usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed several camera setups the way you are describing for friends and my house.  I use an outdoor 90 degree outdoor junction box like these to bring the wire into the house.  I use silicone sealant in the hole in the stucco and the back of the junction box.
[image]

you insert 1 plug at a time through the hole.  I use a short 1 1/2 " pvc pipe through the wall.  The pipe in the back of the junction box can be inserted into the pipe that goes through the wall.

On the inside, I use a plastic electrical box and drill a large hole in the back for the wires to pass through.  For the cover on the inside, I use the plate with the large hole in the middle or take a blank cover and cut the hole to the size you want.

See diagram below:

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused how you install the 90 in your wall. Does the hole pointing down protrude outside the stucco side wall and the horizontal facing hole is inside the wall, and you feed the cables through the bottom? How do you mount the 90?